# ImportError: No module with Popen subprocess other file in same folder from terminal/cron

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, python-import, sys

When I execute the `exec.py` (structure below), directly from the terminal *or* cronjob the execution is working fine. However when I want to check if the script `exec.py` is already running and check this status plus terminate and/or launch `exec.py` from the file `cron.py`. (**Note: it is correctly working in PyCharm**) I get:

`ImportError no module found named layer_a_first.layer_a_second.functions`

Below command directly from terminal or cronjob is working correctly:

`/home/user/project/venv/bin/python3.6 /home/user/project/layer_a_first/layer_a_second/exec.py`

My project structure is:

```
project/
|-- layer_a_first/
|   |-- layer_a_second/
|   |   |-- exec.py
|   |   |-- cron.py
|   |   |-- functions.py
|-- layer_b_first/
|   |-- functions.py
```

Where I have some functions called in **`exec.py`**:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/project')

from layer_a_first.layer_a_second.functions import func_a
from layer_b_first.functions import func_b


# Call func_a
func_a()

# Call func_b
func_b()
```

And the check/terminate/launch script in **`cron.py`**:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/project')

import psutil
from subprocess import Popen

# Check/terminate/launch function
def launch():
    proccron = 'exec.py'
    for process in psutil.process_iter():
        if process.cmdline() == ['python', proccron]:
            print('Process ' + proccron + ' found. Terminating it.')
            process.terminate()
            Popen(['python', proccron])
            print('Process ' + proccron + ' restarting.')
            break
    else:
        print('Process ' + proccron + ' not found: starting it.')
        Popen(['python', proccron])

launch()
```

When i launch `cron.py` in PyCharm it is working correctly. But when I use the terminal or cronjob command I get the above mentioned `ImportError`:

`/home/user/project/venv/bin/python3.6 /home/user/project/layer_a_first/layer_a_second/cron.py`

I have tried a lot with changing the `sys.path` directory or using `os.chdir` to jump to the correct directory. It is all not working. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Preferably so it is still working in terminal and PyCharm but the terminal command has priority.

Many many thanks for taking the time to help me out!!

Comment: Make sure your project root is configured properly and the packages `layer_a_first` and `layer_b_first` have at least empty `__init__.py`  in them.

Comment: @dmitryro Nice one! That solves the first problem. But now I get the `ImportError: No module named requests` error. Where `requests` package is used in functions.py

Comment: please be sure, that you show all `__init__.py` files, that are in the directories.
Omitting them makes it difficult to help.
There should be one in layer_a_first, one in layer_b_first and one in layer_a_first/layer_a_second

The files may be empty

Comment: Verify your python interpreter is the right one in settings - see if it's chosen correctly and is used with the project, points to the right root location and has all the dependencies needed installed.

Comment: do you really use the same python executable in all setups.
It seems as if you installed requests (perhaps in a virtualenv), which you use in the working scenarios, but the cronjob is perhaps not working.

Perhaps you change the environment variable path in your ~/.bashrc (or equivalent if you use another shell)

cronjobs don't source ~/.bashrc.

Try to use the absolute path of the python executable, that you want to use in your cronjob, this will probably fix the issue.

you can use `print(sys.executable)` from a working scenario to see which python is used

Comment: @gelonida Thanks for helping! The python3.6 interpreter in the venv has the right packages installed. The weird thing is: when I use `source venv/bin/activate` first in terminal and afterwards the in the question mentioned execution command for cron.py, it is working.. But only from within the venv terminal, when the specified venv python3.6 should also be working right?

Comment: virtualenvs are only activated for the current terminal and for subprocesses, that are started from this terminal (except something resets it explicitly)


I don't use pycharm, but I think in pycharm you can specify which python should be used for executing a project.

If not you might try to quit all pycharm sessions, then `source venv/bin/activate` and then start pycharm from this terminal.
However as I mentioned it might be that pycharm resets the PATH var and ignores your current virtualenv

Comment: check if `requests` is installed; `pip list | grep requests` and `python -c 'import requests'`.

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks for the help guys! The venv was not called in the Popen command, fixed that with setting `os.environ['PATH'} to the venv folder